# Is there a voice chat version of the Server Fault 'Comms Room'?

Tags: discussion

Is there a voice chat version of the Server Fault 'Comms Room'?

Perhaps using the TeamSpeak 3 protocol?

Comment: Orrr... Google Plus Hangout?

Comment: @WesleyDavid Google plus what?

Answer (score 11):

Why yes *indeed* there is!

It's at ts3server://46.20.116.64?port=10767 and there's no password, but please do use your Server Fault user name on there too to save confusion.

Comment: Now, only if there were something like a conference bridge so I could act like I was on a very important conference call using my desk line..

Comment: @AaronCopley Get cracking on an Asterisk2TeamSpeak module...

Comment: @AaronCopley: You're *totally* using your soft phone.